# Why doesn't the conda windows 64 repo have certain versions of Python?

Tags: python, conda

[This](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64/) is the repo and on searching for the python versions available (searching page for "python-3.6.") I noticed that 3.6.0 was not available. Python 3.6.2 upwards was available.

What difference would it actually make if I'm running an old [code](https://github.com/for-ai/CipherGAN/commit/7304f009619fa8016fc55a94417b632b5182b11c) that specifically mentions compatibility with just 2.7.12 and 3.6. ?

Comment: compatible with 3.6 generally implies that its compatible with all micro versions 3.6.x unless otherwise stated

Answer (score 1):

The [three groups of numbers in a Python version](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/) are "major", "minor", and "micro":

> - new *major versions* are exceptional; they only come when strongly incompatible changes are deemed necessary, and are planned very long in advance;
> - new *minor versions* are feature releases; they get released annually, from the current in-development branch;
> - new *micro versions* are bugfix releases; they get released roughly every 2 months; they are prepared in maintenance branches.

Micro versions don't introduce features or break backwards compatibility. Anything that runs on, for instance, 3.6.1 should run just as well on 3.6.2, and so on. (The exception would be code that accidentally *relies* on a bug, but that's pretty rare.)

Generally speaking, you should use the newest micro version available.